# iPhone auto brightness

Tags: display, iphone

I reset the settings (all settings) on my new iPhone 5 today, to try to troubleshoot some problem. Since doing so, my screen seems dimmer.

I never changed the brightness settings to begin with, from opening the factory-sealed box up until the reset, so I am not sure why this seems to be the case. The auto-brightness seems to be using a lower intensity for any given lighting condition since the reset.

Am I just imagining things, or is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably are just imagining things, unless dirt has been obstructing your ambient light sensor and beside resetting your settings, you cleaned it too.

Comment: Where is the sensor? I use a microfiber cloth and a drop of camera lens cleaner to wipe down the front every night.